# How to solve a second order ODE with Dirac delta inhomogeneity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I am working with the following second order ODE
\begin{equation}
y''(x) - q² y(x) = F \delta(x - x_0)
\end{equation}
on the domain $-L/2$ to $+L/2$ without specifying any boundary conditions for now. The solution to this problem I found in the literature is
\begin{equation}
y(x) = A \cosh(qx) + B \sinh(qx) + \frac{F}{2q} e^{q|x-x_0|} .
\end{equation}
However, I can not reconstruct this result. I am not sure how to split the solution into two parts before and after the Dirac spike.
Here is how far I have come:
The solution to the homogeneous equation can be obtained from the Ansatz
\begin{equation}
y(x) = A e^{-qx} + B e^{qx} .
\end{equation}
For the non-homogeneous equation I try variation of parameters starting from
\begin{equation}
y(x) = C(x) e^{-qx} + D(x) e^{qx} .
\end{equation}
Plugging this Ansatz into the ODE and introducing the constrain $C'(x) e^{-qx} + D'(x) e^{qx} = 0$ allows me to solve for the coefficients $C'(x)$ and $D'(x)$
\begin{equation}
C'(x) = - \frac{F}{2q} \delta(x - x_0) e^{qx} \quad \text{and} \quad D'(x) = \frac{F}{2q} \delta(x - x_0) e^{-qx} .
\end{equation}
Integrating these equations then gives
\begin{equation}
C(x_0) = - \frac{F}{2q} e^{qx_0} \quad \text{and} \quad D(x_0) = \frac{F}{2q} e^{-qx_0},
\end{equation}
which do not depend on $x$ anymore, but only $x_0$. This can now be used to obtain the full solution to the ODE
\begin{equation}
y(x) = A e^{-qx} + B e^{qx} + \frac{F}{2q} \left( e^{q(x - x_0)} - e^{q(x_0 - x)} \right) .
\end{equation}
I think the homogeneous part of mine is somewhat similar to the solution from the literature. I am more concerned what I missed in constructing the last term. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: An anti-derivative of the Dirac delta is a unit jump or ramp function. Using this consistently, both parts fit together like in the reference solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fourier transform is the most common way of dealing with a delta source :
$$
-k^2\hat{y}(k)-q^2\hat{y}(k)=F \verb+ +\Rightarrow\verb+ + \hat{y}(k) = -\frac{F}{k^2+q^2}
$$
and the inverse transform gives the desired result.

---

If you want to use the variation of parameters, note that when integrating $C'(x)$ :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
C(x)-C(-L/2) 
   &=& \displaystyle
    -\frac{F}{2q}\int_{-L/2}^xe^{qx'}\delta(x'-x_0)\,\mathrm{d}x' \\
   &\equiv& \displaystyle 
   -\frac{F}{2q}e^{qx_0}\int_{-L/2}^x\delta(x'-x_0)\,\mathrm{d}x' \\
   &=& \displaystyle 
   -\frac{F}{2q}e^{qx_0}(H(x-x_0)-H(-L/2-x_0))
\end{array}
$$
where $H = \delta'$ is the Heaviside function. The constant of integration $C(-L/2)$ can be assumed to be zero. Note that $H(-L/2-x_0) = 0$ since $-L/2 < x_0$. After calculating $D(x)$ in the same manner, you find the particular solution to be
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
y_P(x) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   -\frac{F}{2q}e^{qx_0}H(x-x_0) \cdot e^{-qx} + \frac{F}{2q}e^{-qx_0}H(x-x_0) \cdot e^{qx} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{F}{2q}\left(e^{q(x-x_0)}-e^{-q(x-x_0)}\right)H(x-x_0) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{F}{q}\sinh(q(x-x_0))H(x-x_0)
\end{array}
$$
which is the required result.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I see how the Fourier transform gives the reference solution. However I do not quite get the Heaviside step function part. Does it not just pull the solution to zero for $x < x_0$ whereas the reference solution gives a decaying exponential for $x < x_0$ and an ascending exponential for $x > x_0$? The reference solution is continuous at $x_0$, the solution involving the Heaviside step function however is not?

Comment: @tscherenkov The solution you found in the litterature corresponds to the one you would get with the Fourier transform (even if there is a sign error, it should be $e^{-q|x-x_0|}$). Both solutions are correct, since we only need one particular solution among all. Nonetheless, the Heaviside solution would be more meaningful in physical situations, because it implies that the system only reacts after the $\delta$ bump, so that this solution follows causality.